# Does the dot operator cost anything in terms of operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

I have a loop like

```
for (int i = 2; i <= ViewBag.numPages; ++i)
```

and I'm wondering if it'll be faster if I write it as

```
for (int i = 2, n = ViewBag.numPages; i <= n; ++i)
```

Please give me a deep (low-level) explanation if possible

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/is-it-costly-to-do-array-length-or-list-count-in-a-loop or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/performance-difference-for-control-structures-for-and-foreach-in-c-sharp

Comment: If it does, the compiler will optimize it anyway, unless you turn that off.  Even then, the cost is likely to be very small, like two machine instructions.

Comment: Also: recommended reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844781/Digging-Into-NET-Loop-Performance-Bounds-checking

Comment: @PaulKienitz: It could be costly. Although not in C#, in C you could have a structure allocated in RAM. Accessing that repeatedly (using `->` notation) would be extremely costly as RAM access would take far longer than register memory.

Comment: You have an odd definition of ”extremely”.  First of all, re-hitting the same address would be cached.  Second, ram access cost wouldn't be extreme until your loop counts were starting to worry about overflowing an int32.

Comment: @PaulKienitz: Ok, maybe "extremely" is a bit of an exaggeration, but it could add up, especially if the loop has loops within loops.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/262955/4635947

Comment: By the way.  You are not Donald Knuth.. shame on you to misuse the name and ask such a simple question that the real person would know for sure!

Comment: @BasvanStein agreed. Downvoted just for that reason.

Comment: @BasvanStein Anyone who knows who Donald Knuth is will obviously understand that OP is not Donald Knuth.

Comment: @Rotem, agreed, but I just don't like fakers.

Comment: @Rotem still, distasteful practice IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ViewBag.numPages` stays constant for the duration of your loop, I would favor the second variant, i.e.:

```
for (int i = 2, n = ViewBag.numPages; i <= n; ++i)
```

Why?

- Perhaps your first `numPages` is a simple field, but if it is a non-trivial property, your loop has to evaluate it (call its getter) before each iteration, which is certainly costlier than evaluating it once and then caching the result.
- Compiler optimizations are an implementation detail of the compiler, you do not know what exactly the compiler does for you to improve performance.

  Caching `ViewBag.numPages` manually means that you won't have to rely on an optimization that the compiler may or may not do for you.

That being said, if `ViewBag.numPages` is a (constant) field, not a property, then both code variants are likely so close in execution speed (in the best case, we're talking about the difference between accessing a CPU register vs. accessing atomically one memory location that might be in the CPU memory cache) that the difference doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the dot operator cost anything in terms of operations?

It depends.  For your ASP.NET code:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= ViewBag.numPages; ++i)
```

...then the above may be subject to optimisations (or perhaps CPU caching) so anything you do in an attempt to optimise may not be noticeable.

### COM

However, your question **title** does not mention ASP.NET (though it is later tagged [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) ) so imagine if `ViewBag` was actually a **COM object**.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= ViewBag.numPages; ++i)
```

...then that would be very expensive and not subject to .NET optimisation I would not think.  Invoking COM, particularly via `IDispatch` is significantly slower than accessing a .NET property on a local object.

So in the case of COM you should:

```
for (int i = 2, n = ViewBag.numPages; i <= n; ++i)
```

Comment: How could the CPU cache the value without asserting that no other thread is changing `ViewBag.numPages` during the loop?

Comment: Asp.net It is in the tags though..

Comment: @BasvanStein Agreed.  I don't believe the question to be significantly tied to ASP.NET though. :)

Comment: @Rotem Simple - you have few guarantees about staleness of data in multi-threading. It's one of the things that makes multi-threading rather hard. The CPU will track changes to the memory location and flush the relevant cache lines if necessary, just as with single-threaded code - however, it doesn't happen immediately.