# What is the standard way to find the elements count in a 2D jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

```
    public static double PrazenWindowDensity(double [][] Xn, double x, double sigma2)
    {
        double gauss = 0;

        foreach(double [] arr in Xn)
        {
            foreach (double item in arr)
            {
                double xx = GausianFunction(item, x, sigma2);
                gauss += xx;
            }
        }

        return gauss / Xn.Length; //this is surely incorrect. Isn't it?
    }
```

**What can I write here?**

```
return gauss / Xn.Length;
```

Comment: As you are already doing a loop, not know if linq is faster or just add `count++` inside the inner foreach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/is-it-costly-to-do-array-length-or-list-count-in-a-loop

Comment: @Eric, hmmm...correct you are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest, and easiest approach I think is

```
public static double PrazenWindowDensity(double[][] Xn, double x, double sigma2)
{
    double gauss=0;
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<Xn.Length; i++)
    {
        gauss+=Xn[i].Sum((item) => GausianFunction(item, x, sigma2));
        count+=Xn[i].Length;
    }
    return gauss/count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a satisfactory answer, so I'll go ahead and post it as one.

```
return gauss / Xn.Sum(x => x.Length);
```